# Using powershell SeImpersonatePrivilege granting to managed service account

Tags: kerberos, impersonation, service-accounts

i created managed service account for my service.
I need to add to this account SeImpersonatePrivilege
It's windows 2008 r2
How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Impersonate a client after authentication" in the
Local Security Policy under Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment

Also NTRights with `SeImpersonatePrivilege`:

```
ntrights.exe +r SeImpersonatePrivilege -u domain\managedserviceaccount$
```